# Possible to open/convert Office 98 for Mac PowerPoint file

Tags: file-conversion, ms-office

Is it possible to open or convert a Mac Office 98 PowerPoint file (.pp)?  I don't need to edit it, just either convert it to a more recent version or save as a pdf. I don't have access to anything before OS X, but I still have a PowerPC laptop. Recent versions of PowerPoint refuse to open it, and I haven't been successful finding a converter.  Alternatively, is there a service that would do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of free online converters out there that will convert many different file types to PDF.  I had to convert some Microsoft Works documents to Work once and the zamar.com worked great.  Try one of these out:

http://www.freepdfconvert.com

http://www.zamzar.com

http://document.online-convert.com/convert-to-pdf

Let me know if any of these help you out.  Good luck!

Comment: I'll give these a try.